# What do I use to describe the difference between two groups in terms of found latent variables

Tags: multivariate-analysis, group-differences

I need to describe what the difference between two groups (patients and normal controls) consists of in terms of latent variables that I can describe *within* each group.

For instance, given this PCA variable map:

[image]

how do I compare this to with the same latent variables in another group (in this case, the control group)?

Edit:

That is, what I would like to do is add more individuals to the data set, and a factor specifying which kind the individual described in the row is. From that, if possible, I would like to describe the changes in associations of the measures with the most associated component (in this case Dim 1 for most measures) when going from one group to the other.

That is, describe what characterises the differences between the groups.

Comment: PCA is a descriptive technique - there's no sense of generalization to a population in PCA, so such a comparison doesn't make sense (and principal components aren't latent). In EFA, you can do a procrustes rotation to a target matrix.

Comment: Or do you mean compare the means of the PCs?

Comment: Yes, I know PCA is descriptive. What I would like to do is add more individuals to the data set, and a factor specifying which kind the individual described in the row is. From that, if possible, I would like to describe the changes in associations of the measures with the most associated component (in this case Dim 1 for most measures) when going from one group to the other. (If this makes sense?). I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Actually PCA is not just descriptive method but a statistical model, see for example http://liorpachter.wordpress.com/2014/05/26/what-is-principal-component-analysis/, and it does make sense to ask what the PCA is estimating and how well.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. Are you using factor to mean component, or something else? What do you mean by 'kind' in this context?